# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:42)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to run a simple code in eclipse but it is not working.

Details:
Firefox version - 61.0b4 (64-bit), Jdk - jdk1.8.0_121, Eclipse oxygen

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestBrowsers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Error description:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at TestBrowsers.main(TestBrowsers.java:8)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;) with Selenium, gradle and ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021707/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkstatezlj)

Answer (score 0):

May not fix the issue but there is a potential misspelling, highlighted in (). 
Firefox(b)Driver driver = new FirefoxDriver();